# How to search string under cursor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In vim, pressing <kbd>*</kbd> in command mode performs an automatic search of the word under the cursor. How can I obtain the same in Eclipse?

Comment: It is perfectly solved here.............................
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6420236/5840893

Answer (score 7):

A combination of two keystrokes:

1. First, hit Ctrl + Shift + Right Arrow  to invoke "Select Enclosing Element". This will select the word under your cursor.
2. Use Ctrl + K (Cmd + K on OS X) to "find next".

Comment: About (1): `Ctrl+Shift+Right Arrow` selects from the cursor until the end of the word, not the whole word (suppose the cursor is in the middle). To really select the enclosing element (at least in Eclipse Helios) press `Alt+Shift+Up`

Comment: Some Eclipse editors may not support "Select Enclosing Element", so "Backward Word" + `Ctrl+Shift+Right` is the next best thing.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Right is cumbersome - you need to press it several times to select a word with upper/lower mixed. Suppose your cursor was under "myAccountBalanceOld", then you need at least 1 "Backward Word" + 4 (Ctrl+Shift+Right) + (Ctrl+k) = 6 keys. Often I end up pressing from 5 to 10 keystroke for a single string search depending upon the string. Despite years of evolution, it is discouraging to have these awkward key combination for simple things in No.1 Open Source IDE tool, which in MS Visual Studio can be done with a single Ctrl+F3. Hail Open Source? Perhaps not.

Answer (score 4):

It appears [it was not possible in 2004](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg13717.html), and it's still not possible, apparently. I'm speechless...

Comment: VS has done this since the dawn of time, filling in the word under the cursor as the default when ^F is pressed.  Sometimes, it seems as though people never use their competition to see the trivial, blatantly obvious things like this that they're missing.  It's like they think they can make a better product by developing in a closed vacuum and never learning from the rest of the world...

Answer (score 1):

I also need this functionality and created a small plug-in which adds commands for doing this. You can download it and find more details here: http://eclipselabs.org/p/eclipse-tweaks/

Comment: Hello. Is your useful plug-in still available?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10, tested on Eclipse `2020-03`:

**Two Steps:**
1. `Alt + Shift + Up Arrow`, to select the word under the cursor
2. `Ctrl + K` to find the selected word *forward*
(Ctrl + Shift + K to find the selected word *backward*)

**NOTE:**
If you are inside an XML tag, `Alt + Shift + Up Arrow` will select from the beginning of the tag to the end tag, including all enclosing elements. Try it!

**BONUS:**
`Ctrl + Shift + Down/Up arrows` to navigate methods, as sometimes the selected word is a method you want to go to.

Better still,
`Ctrl + O` - Go to a specific method, by searching (Just enter the first few letters of the method, and Enter)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> on a Windows machine. On a Mac, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> should work (seen [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EclipseIde)).

Comment: It does perform a search, but not of what's currently under the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Not *exactly* the same, but maybe helpfull if you work with java. In a .java file you can press

```
CTRL + SHIFT + u
```

to find occurences in the same source file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Shift + Ctrl + K to search next backwards.