# Eclipse CDT : C++ Editor window, select word under cursor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse after coming from a well known commercial IDE. I am struggling with a very simple user requirement.

> I want to search for the word under the
>   cursor with one key press!

The only way I know to select the element at the cursor is mouse double click. CTRL-LEFT/RIGHT, moves the cursor to start/end of the current word, with a SHIFT selecting as it goes. This means you need to CTRL-LEFT, CTRL-SHIFT-RIGHT - CTRL-K to do a search.

So if I can map the double click functionality to a keyboard key, my problem is solved - "Mapped Key" + CTRL-K.

Comment: move focus to the control(button, or menu), then click 'enter' or 'space'

Comment: Please explain the -1? It's not helpful to -1 without some comment as to why you belive what I have asked is not a valid question.

Comment: Instead of CTRL-LEFT, CTRL-SHIFT-RIGHT, you can do SHIFT-ALT-UP (expand selection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu option `Edit | Find Word` does what you want. It doesn't have any keybinding by default, but you can add one in `Window | Preferences`, `General -> Keys`